# Firefox's scrollbar is practically invisible - how to change

Tags: firefox, colors, scrollbar, edit, stylish

how to edit Firefox 'basic page style'
for all sites
with a Stylish script
to **set scrollbar to a higher contrast color**.

I can't see the thing its terrible.
is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Change your Windows settings. Right-click on the desktop and click "Personalize" (or "Settings").

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbar is an operating system feature, not a feature of your website. Its look-and-feel are controlled by the user, not the webpage. IE provides a way to change scrollbar colors but it was heavily abused in the early days and is now considered a generally bad idea. In short, if you are trying to manipulate scrollbars from a webpage you're going to have to code a 'fake' scrollbar in Javascript or forget about it.

If you are trying to change only your own system then you may find some possibilities in creating user chrome, greasemonkey script or persona. I'm not sure what is possible there.

Comment: If you don't like the default scrollbar style that matches the OS, then unfortunately a custom theme is the only way to go, because most scrollbars are "native anonymous content" and can't be styled by normal means.